# Inflate two views for one Array item in a recycler adapter

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I have a **cardView** xml

My model Person is

[image]

My Adapter is pretty Generic and Attaching code is showing errors so not attaching it

I initialise a Arraylist for adapter

```
persons = new ArrayList<>();
persons.add(new Person("Emma Wilson", "25 years old", 1));
persons.add(new Person("Lavery Maiss", "27 years old", 2));
persons.add(new Person("Lillie Watts", "35 years old", 3));
```

If **age=25** like **Emma Wilson** for a person, I want to inflate the
**view(cardView.xml) twice**.

I cannot change the **ArrayList**.

I want to do it using the adapter itself. Is this possible and how to do it?

Comment: Can you share the code from the adapter?

Comment: @KevinWallis : I tried doing it but it keeps showing error that 4 spaces required.Could not resolve it. [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a view that includes `cardView.xml` twice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include android:id="@+id/cv1" layout="@layout/card_view.xml" />
    <include android:id="@+id/cv2" layout="@layout/card_view.xml" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your adapter,

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   // Get the data item for this position
   Person person = getItem(position);    
   // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
   if (person.age == 25) {
      convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.twice.xml, parent, false);
   }else{
      convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.once.xml, parent, false);
  }

  //populate views...


}
```